# what is the type of i18next " t " variable (TYPESCRIPT)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, i18next

I use i18next and I want to pass the t function prop to my interface.

exp:

```
const { t } = useTranslation();

export interface ITranslate {
   translate: ... type?
}
```

what is the type of the " t " variable ?

Comment: You should be able to use "Jump to Definition" in your code editor to see what its type is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maybe this will work:

```
import { TFunction } from "react-i18next";

export interface ITranslate {
   translate: TFunction
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way is just to use

```
t: typeof i18next.t
```

In this scenario if you also used `<const>` operator for translation files it will guard input in the translation function, while `TFunction` will not.

Example of `<const>` usage for translations:

```
# translations.ts file

import en from "./en.json"
import fr from "./fr.json"
import cz from "./cz.json"

export default <const>{
  en,
  fr,
  cz
}    

# i18next.d.ts file
    
    import translations from "./translations"
    
    declare module "i18next" {
      interface CustomTypeOptions {
        defaltNS: 'en',
        resources: typeof translations["en"]
      }
    }
```

In this way you will have following results in imagined app:

```
# en.json file
{
  "first": "This is first",
  "second": "This is second"
}

# Component.tsx file
import i18next from "18next";

const shouldWork = i18next.t('first')
const shouldFail = i18next.t('third') // TS will show an error
```

Be sure to have `"resolveJsonModule": true` in `tsconfig.json` file

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility type:

```
export interface ITranslate {
   translate: ReturnType<typeof useTranslation>['t']
}
```

Comment: I got this error: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.

Comment: @universe11 if you can show something reproducible, I can help you further. A link to a stackblitz snippet will do, then post the link here